# Programming a Atmega32U4 via USBASP

Tags: hardware, atmega, atmel, microprocessors, avrdude

I created my own custom board and added a ICSP header, although I can't seem to program it.

My board has a Atmega32U4 (no external crystal) and I keep getting an error when I use the command:

```
avrdude -p m32u4 -c usbasp -B 64 -U flash:w:/Users/Jbonnett/Desktop/RGBWstrandtest.ino.hex
```

The error:

```
avrdude: set SCK frequency to 8000 Hz 
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.
```

As you can see I am trying to program the chip in slow mode and I also tried the hardware jumper for slow mode. Although the error is telling me that it can't see my custom board.

The programmer that I am using is this one: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USBASP-USB-ISP-Programmer-for-Atmel-AVR-ATMega328-ATMega32U4-Arduino/322662323277

Here are a couple of photos to show that the custom board is wired up correctly:
[image: Programmer powered (no power LED on custom board)]
[image: Custom board powered programmer]
Please note that the programmer can be powered by the custom board.

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: [My Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTOWe.png)

Comment: add schematics of the custom board to question. is the 2x3 header a standard Arduino ISCP header?

Comment: Hi @Juraj I added my schematic :)

Comment: do you have a not-by-you-made 32u4 board? you could try the programmer first with that

Comment: Sorry I don't no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I added a crystal and it works! Even though it has an internal one I have no idea why it didn't work without one :(

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information, there are many possibilities, you could check the following, though not a comprehensive list, should narrow it down:

(1) Try using the -F parameter to check if you can get a little further

(2) Check if the USBAsp works with a standard 32u4 board

(3) Check if the ISP header connections are correct, sometimes the labeling of the pins might be reversed due to any mistake in the schematic/layout/fab

(4) The Fuses on the 32u4 may be set to use external oscillator (though I have never seen this setting on factory 32u4, default is always internal RC), in which case we need an external crystal to program.

Comment: Hi @coolbreeze, I did try the -F argument with no joy. I can't see the USBAsp not working although I have no information on compatibility. Here is my schematic [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/bpC5PfE.png). Any idea how to set the correct fuses? I haven't got the slightest clue when it comes to them.

Comment: If you could post the output of avrdude when using the -F option, it would help. Also add the -v option for verbose output.

Comment: ISP Header seems to be ok from the schematic, need to check if there are any connectivity/soldering problems on board.

Is the chip a new 32u4 from the factory( direct from one of the Atmel dealers) or has this been programmed previously (by you or sourced from one of the sources who pre-program the chips with code)?

Comment: I purchased it from here, although I can't see if it ships with a bootloader pre-installed.

Comment: Sorry I must have forgot the link :( [Link to ATMega32U4-MUR](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/ATMEL-AVR_ATMEL_ATMEGA32U4_ATMEGA32U4-MUR_C45874.html) See section 21.4 in the documentation.

Comment: Also adding -F gives an output of:

avrdude.exe: set SCK frequency to 8000 Hz
avrdude.exe: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude.exe: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude.exe: Expected signature for ATmega32U4 is 1E 95 87
avrdude.exe: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
             To disable this feature, specify the -D option.

avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.